# Show multiple registered user`s location on the same map (Android Studio, Firebase, Kotlin)

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

So my app shows my location on the map, and it also saves the latitude/longitude onto Firebase. This is how it looks like:

[image]

The current path of my user location is just "/users/userlocation".
However, I want to save "userlocation" under each user, then I want all these markers to be shown on the same map which I already created here:

MapsActivity:

```
    private lateinit var map: GoogleMap
    private val LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST = 1
    private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private lateinit var locationRequest: LocationRequest
    private lateinit var locationCallback: LocationCallback


    private fun getLocationAccess() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            getLocationUpdates()
            startLocationUpdates()
        }
        else
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST)
    }

    private fun getLocationUpdates() {
            locationRequest = LocationRequest()
            locationRequest.interval = 30000
            locationRequest.fastestInterval = 20000
            locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY

            locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
                override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                    if (locationResult.locations.isNotEmpty()) {
                        val location = locationResult.lastLocation

                        lateinit var databaseRef: DatabaseReference
                        databaseRef = Firebase.database.reference
                        val locationlogging = LocationLogging(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                        databaseRef.child("/users/userlocation").setValue(locationlogging)

                                .addOnSuccessListener {
                                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Locations written into the database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                                }
                                .addOnFailureListener {
                                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Error occured while writing the locations", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                                }


                        if (location != null) {
                            val latLng = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                            val markerOptions = MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
                            map.addMarker(markerOptions)
                            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15f))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun startLocationUpdates() {
        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,locationCallback, null)
    }


    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        if (requestCode == LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST) {
            if (grantResults.contains(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            } else { Toast.makeText(this, "User has not granted location access permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                finish()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    }


    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        map = googleMap
        getLocationAccess()
    }
}
```

And here is what I have tried:

```
@Parcelize
class User(val uid: String, val username: String, val profileImageUrl: String, locationlogging: String): Parcelable {
  constructor() : this("", "", "", "")
}
```

I added "locationlogging" as a string in my User.kt file, but I might be completely wrong here.

I tried to add this into my RegisterActivity, within my saveUserToFirebaseDatabase Function:

```
 // Save user to firebase database
 private fun saveUserToFirebaseDatabase(profileImageUrl: String) {
        val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid ?: ""
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/$uid")
        val user = User(uid, username_edittext_register.text.toString(), profileImageUrl)
}
```

I am not 100% sure, but I think this is the part where I should implement the user`s location, so it should be added to all registered members, the same way as profile image URL, uid, and username. Anything I try gives me errors. Am I completely off-track?
How do I add the locations for each of the registered users into my firebase to show all of them at the same time on the Google Map?

Comment: You have to denormalize the data to another node where you get the shallow information needed for the pin/profile plus the location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current path to location is:

```
/users/userlocation
```

Which doesn't seem to be correct, because every User object should have its own location. To achieve that, you can go ahead with one of the following three approaches:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- users
       |
       --- $uid
            |
            --- profileImageUrl: "https://..."
            |
            --- uid: "h9xZs...bV82"
            |
            --- username: "Bad Pug"
            |
            --- location
                  |
                  --- latitude: 53.37...
                  |
                  --- longitude: -0.90...
```

Meaning that "location" is a Map containing the latitude and longitude. The second approach might be to add both latitude and longitude directly under the User object:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- users
       |
       --- $uid
            |
            --- profileImageUrl: "https://..."
            |
            --- uid: "h9xZs...bV82"
            |
            --- username: "Bad Pug"
            |
            --- latitude: 53.37...
            |
            --- longitude: -0.90...
```

If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), you can use a geographical point, as it's a [supported data type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). Your Firestore schema might look like this:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- users (collection)
       |
       --- $uid (document)
            |
            --- profileImageUrl: "https://..."
            |
            --- uid: "h9xZs...bV82"
            |
            --- username: "Bad Pug"
            |
            --- geoPoint: [53.37...° N,  -0.90...° E]
```

The key to solving this issue is to add either a Map (for the first solution), two new double properties (for the second solution), or a GeoPoint object (for the third solution), and populate with the corresponding latitude and longitude values. Once you write the User object to the database, you'll have one of the schema from above.

**Edit:**

In code, to get for example the latitude and longitude in the second example, please use the following lines of code:

```
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
val rootRef =  FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val usersRef = rootRef.collection("users")
val uidRef = usersRef.document(uid)
uidRef.get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
        if (document != null) {
            val latitude = document.getDouble("latitude")
            val longitude = document.getDouble("longitude")
            Log.d(TAG, latitude + ", " + longitude)
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No such document")
        }
    }
    .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", exception)
    }
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
53.37..., -0.90...
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it become more understandable now. How this coding would look like in practice within my map activity? Also, if I implement any of these ideas that you mentioned (let's say the most logical and easier) and each user will have the coordinates, will that automatically comes up on the map activity as a marker?

Comment: It will look like as in my updated answer. Once you have the latitude and longitude, you can add the marker on Google Maps. It won't be added automatically, you should [write some code for that](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map-with-marker).

Comment: Thank you for the help. I followed your instructions, and the different device coordinates started to appear in my Logcat, however nothing has changed in my Firebase Real time database. What did I do wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: What happened now is, all my user details have been replaced by the latitude and longitude under /users.

Comment: If the coordinates are displayed in the logcat that's good news, the code worked. Without seeing the code, it's hard to say what's wrong. Most likely you are using set() instead of update().

Comment: If you have hard times implementing the details of adding the markers on the map, please post a new question, so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Hi, I was able to partly solve the firebase tree issue, and my other issue is in my new question. Would you be so kind to have a look at it? Thank you in advance! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67452641/registered-users-location-doesnt-show-on-map-users-cannot-see-each-others-l