# Show multiple user`s location at the same time on a map (Kotlin, Firebase Realtime Database)

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

This question reflects back to a previous question: [Show multiple registered user`s location on the same map (Android Studio, Firebase, Kotlin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67372533/show-multiple-registered-users-location-on-the-same-map-android-studio-fireba/67382887?noredirect=1#comment119192460_67382887)

My main problem is that I have created a chatting app in Android Studio, and also added a map activity, using Google Api. I am using Firebase Realtime Database, and this is how my tree currently looks like:
[image]

I want the "userlocation" appear under each of my registered user, so all registered user`s location will will appear on my Google Map as a marker.

Here is my MapsActivity:

```
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    companion object {
        var currentUser: User? = null
        val TAG = "MapsActivity"
    }



    private lateinit var map: GoogleMap
    private val LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST = 1
    private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private lateinit var locationRequest: LocationRequest
    private lateinit var locationCallback: LocationCallback


    private fun getLocationAccess() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            getLocationUpdates()
            startLocationUpdates()
        }
        else
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST)


    }



    private fun getLocationUpdates() {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest()
        locationRequest.interval = 30000
        locationRequest.fastestInterval = 20000
        locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY

        locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                if (locationResult.locations.isNotEmpty()) {
                    val location = locationResult.lastLocation




//                    val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
//                    val rootRef =  FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
//                    val usersRef = rootRef.collection("users")
//                    val uidRef = uid?.let { usersRef.document(it) }
//                    if (uidRef != null) {
//                        uidRef.get()
//                                .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
//                                    if (document != null) {
//                                        val latitude = document.getDouble("latitude")
//                                        val longitude = document.getDouble("longitude")
//                                        Log.d(TAG, ", " + location.latitude + location.longitude)
//                                    } else {
//                                        Log.d(TAG, "No such document")
//                                    }
//                                }
//                                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
//                                    Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", exception)
//                                }
//                    }


                    lateinit var databaseRef: DatabaseReference
                    databaseRef = Firebase.database.reference
                    val locationlogging = LocationLogging(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                    databaseRef.child("/userlocation").setValue(locationlogging)

                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Locations written into the database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener {
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Error occured while writing your location to the database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }

                }

            }
        }
    }




    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun startLocationUpdates() {
        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,locationCallback, null)
    }


    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        if (requestCode == LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST) {
            if (grantResults.contains(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            } else { Toast.makeText(this, "User has not granted location access permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                finish()
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)

          
        

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    }


    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        map = googleMap
        getLocationAccess()
    }




    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.nav_menu_map, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```

I commented out some of the codes as I wasn`t able to implement it properly. When I ran the code, the latitude and longitude appeared in my Logcat, but in my Realtime database, it wiped out all my data under /users and it was replaced by the latitude and longitude.

Here is my LocationLogging:

```
import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties

@IgnoreExtraProperties

data class LocationLogging(
    var Latitude: Double? = 0.0,
    var Longitude: Double? = 0.0
)
```

I am looking to find an easy way, which puts the coordinates into my Firebase Realtime Database under each of my registered users, and show all locations on the map at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current user with the firebase auth SDK and change the path where you save the data to save it under the user path. You would need to change this part of your code:

```java
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
 lateinit var databaseRef: DatabaseReference
                    databaseRef = Firebase.database.reference
                    val locationlogging = LocationLogging(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                    databaseRef.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("userlocation").setValue(locationlogging)

                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Locations written into the database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener {
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Error occured while writing your location to the database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I've been looking for this solution for quite a long time now. The latitude and longitude is now being saved under each of my user. However, it doesn't show all user's location on the map. It only shows the device`s location. Do you know an additionnal way to make the markers appear all at the same time on the same map? Thank you

Comment: Thx. Great to hear. Could you pls explain that in another question and show a little bit code for that to.

Comment: My activity for the Google map is provided above, I think that's where it should go, but I might be wrong. My other activites are for the registering/login/messaging pages. The google map only shows the location of one device at once. I am also logged in for another user from my other device, but that one shows 1 marker as well. I want to show all online user's location at the same time within the same map. Is that possible to do?

Comment: Can you pls post that in another question. It would be to much to have both of that on a single one here.